# CSS Not Working?

Tags: html, css

I am unsure why my CSS is not working here.

What am I missing?

***EDIT*** Here is the CSS for the main image and the smaller images:

```
    #luz{z-index:1;}
    #cadel{position:absolute; left:0px; top:490px; z-index:2;}
    #cadel:hover {background: url("../messages/files/tourdefrance/cadel-large.jpg") no-repeat 0px 286px; position:absolute; z-index:3;}
    #two{position:absolute; left: 645px; top:374px; z-index:2;}
    #two:hover {background: url("../messages/files/tourdefrance/2-large.jpg") no-repeat 405px 34px; position:absolute; z-index:3;}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="luz"> 
    <img src="/messages/Files/tourdefrance/LuzArdiden.jpg" width="920" height="690" alt="Luz Ardiden" /> <img id="cadel" src="/messages/Files/tourdefrance/cadel.png" width="229" height="200" alt="Cadel Evans" /> 
    <img id="two" src="/messages/Files/tourdefrance/2.jpg" width="110" height="78" alt="Alberto Contador looking at Lance Armstrong" />
</div>
```

The little images should be over the main image. They are not and I am unsure as to why.

Also when the little images are hovered they should show larger views.

Advice?

***EDIT 2*** Part of the issue turned out to be dreamweaver sticking the code in the wrong place thus FF would not show it. However my hover is not working? Ideas?

Comment: Pretty sure your CSS is working, otherwise I wouldn't see background images, a navigation bar, a layout... try clearing your cache and reloading.

Comment: Code dump. Should this be flagged?

Comment: Most of the CSS is, I am referring to the image and the pictures below the main image of the page. Those two images below the main image should be on top of the other image

Comment: @share your code, we can check the problem???

Comment: I'd say there's a serious flaw in your markup, in there somewhere.

Comment: @UBhapE2: This is an extremely poorly worded question. All you tell us is that your CSS isn't working, then provide a link to a page that shows CSS working. If you have more information or or a desired result, then you have to put that in the original question. Otherwise, how the heck do you expect people to be able to answer it? We aren't mind readers.

Comment: I changed the question to be worded a touch better, sorry I did not do that to begin with. What perplexes me is that I have done this same exact thing before and now it doesn't work.

Comment: @UBhapE2 He just edited it to make the question MUCH better. I was referring to the fact that he gave little to no explanation and basically said "Here's my code, fix it." But he corrected it! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to set a background-image for an image-tag?

That wont work. But thats only part two of your question...

try adding `position:relative;` to `#luz`

edit: I can't see any of your mentioned css applying to your page

Comment: Tried That, doesn't work

Comment: I found part of the problem - Dreamweaver was messing with the code I got that fixed. But the roll-overs do not work.

Comment: sure it does not work, because you are trying to set a BACKGROUND-image to an image. But the image-tag fills all foreground space with the specified image, so you can't see a background image. you could change the width and height via css or if you don't want to load the big image just to show a small version, you have to change the src attribute via javascrip

Comment: Thanks, I will use JS to do what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution put every image in a div and give it absolute position.. 
example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ne3Nv/8/

after that you can play with it as you want.

Comment: why not position the image directly? http://jsfiddle.net/VCHNL/

Comment: in any case it has to work i bet his css location is wrong

Comment: yes, it is not available on his page

Comment: I fixed that, DW stuck it in the wrong place and I did not catch it.